# Add together two numpy masked arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a convenient way to add another array with actual values to masked positions in another array?

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.ma.array([0,1,0], mask=[True, False, True])
arr2 = np.ma.array([2,3,0], mask=[False, False, True])
arr1+arr2

Out[4]:
masked_array(data = [-- 4 --],
         mask = [ True False  True],
   fill_value = 999999)
```

Note: in arr2 the value 2 is not masked -> should be in the resulting array
The result should be [2, 4, --]. I'd think there must be an easy solution for this?

Comment: I find your question confusing. you enter data as `[-- 4 --]`, and you expect `[2, 4, --]` as the output? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: The value 2 in arr2 is not masked, so it should be included in the result. Why does the mask in arr1 "win"?

Comment: the masks are added too, and `bool(False + True)` is True

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this (choosing the logical operator that you want to use for your masks from http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

```
>>> from operator import and_
>>> np.ma.array(arr1.data+arr2.data,mask=map(and_,arr1.mask,arr2.mask))
masked_array(data = [2 4 --],
             mask = [False False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

In Python 3, `map()` returns an iterator and not a list, so it is necessary to add `list()`:

```
>>> np.ma.array(arr1.data+arr2.data,mask=list(map(and_,arr1.mask,arr2.mask)))
```