# Adding 3D masked arrays results in TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, netcdf4, masked-array

I have two 3D masked arrays (netCDF4 files output from climate model) that I want to add together. I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539069/add-together-two-numpy-masked-arrays) and got the following (simplified) code out of it:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from operator import and_
from numpy.ma.core import MaskedArray

with Dataset(dir + 'V10.nc') as file_V10:
    with Dataset(dir + 'U10.nc') as file_U10:
        raw_V10 = file_V10.variables['V10'][744 : 9503, :, :] ** 2
        raw_U10 = file_U10.variables['U10'][744 : 9503, :, :] ** 2                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        10m_raw_squared = MaskedArray(raw_V10[:].data + raw_U10[:].data, mask=list(map(and_,raw_V10.mask, raw_U10.mask)))
```

However, I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 92, in <module>
    10m_raw_squared = MaskedArray(raw_V10[:].data + raw_U10[:].data, mask=list(map(and_,raw_V10.mask, raw_U10.mask)))    
TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable
```

If I try changing the mask from boolean to string (in order to make it iterable) by adding mask.astype('str'), I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 92, in <module>
    10m_raw_squared = MaskedArray(raw_V10[:].data + raw_U10[:].data, mask=list(map(and_,raw_V10.mask.astype('str'),raw_U10.mask.astype('str'))))    
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

I have also tried to add the arrays together using a for-loop, but somehow couldn't get that to work without losing a dimension and the majority of the array elements of the data.

How can I add my two datasets together?

Edit: I called for the class of the dataset and got the following output:

```
<class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'>
```

Comment: for now don't try to use the numpy MaskedArray.  Examine what you get from the Dataset load.  I know numpy well, but NETCDF4 less so.

Comment: first make sure netCDF4 datasets are the same as the numpy masked arrays

Comment: See my edit above, I tested for this before posting the question. The datasets are in fact numpy MaskedArrays!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.logical_and` to create the mask.

```
with Dataset(dir + 'V10.nc') as file_V10:
    with Dataset(dir + 'U10.nc') as file_U10:
        raw_V10 = file_V10.variables['V10'][744 : 9503, :, :] ** 2
        raw_U10 = file_U10.variables['U10'][744 : 9503, :, :] ** 2
        mask = np.logical_and(raw_V10.mask, raw_U10.mask)
        10m_raw_squared = MaskedArray(raw_V10[:].data + raw_U10[:].data, mask=mask)
```